# Testing views in layout using dimension values from dimen.xml throws error in Robolectric 2.2

Tags: android, android-layout, robolectric, android-testing

Am using the robolectric-2.2-20130606.235928-4-jar-with-dependencies.jar in testing the Android app.

view am using in my testing is given below. Dimension value is referred from dimen.xml

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/common_header_button"
android:shadowDy="@dimen/subtitle_offset"
android:text="@string/store"
/>
```

In dimension file i have the item like the below

```
<item name="subtitle_offset" format="float" type="dimen">-1.2</item>
```

I am getting the below error. I searched i didn't see any discussion about this.

```
android.view.InflateException: XML file ..\project\..\libproject\res\layout\layout.xml line #-1 (sorry, not yet implemented): Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
at org.robolectric.shadows.RoboLayoutInflater.onCreateView(RoboLayoutInflater.java:38)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
at com.company.libproject.test.StripesViewAdapterTest.setUp(StripesViewAdapterTest.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:241)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:177)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor50.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java)
at org.robolectric.shadows.RoboLayoutInflater.onCreateView(RoboLayoutInflater.java:38)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
at com.company.libproject.test.StripesViewAdapterTest.setUp(StripesViewAdapterTest.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: huh? ResName{com.company.project:dimen/subtitle_offset}
at org.robolectric.shadows.Converter.convertAndFill(Converter.java:96)
at org.robolectric.shadows.Converter.convertAndFill(Converter.java:50)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.createTypedArray(ShadowResources.java:228)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.attrsToTypedArray(ShadowResources.java:203)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.access$000(ShadowResources.java:51)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources$ShadowTheme.obtainStyledAttributes(ShadowResources.java:460)
at android.content.res.Resources$Theme.obtainStyledAttributes(Resources.java)
at android.widget.TextView.__constructor__(TextView.java:561)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:447)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:442)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
at org.robolectric.shadows.RoboLayoutInflater.onCreateView(RoboLayoutInflater.java:38)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
at com.company.libproject.test.StripesViewAdapterTest.setUp(StripesViewAdapterTest.java:60)
... 21 more
```